# Order of the entries changed after the DFT

Tags: r, matrix, dft

I am trying to understand how the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) works. I generate some data

```
 n<-5
 set.seed(100)
 x<-rnorm(n)
```

and an orthogonal matrix that I use to calculate the DFT

```
 omega<-exp(-2*pi*1i/n)
 E<-n^(-1/2)*omega^(0:(n-1)*matrix(0:(n-1),n,n,byrow=TRUE))
 round(Re(crossprod(E,Conj(E))),15)
```

The DFT is given by

```
 x%*%t(E)
```

Indeed, we can check that this coincides with the result given by `fft`

```
 round(n^(-1/2)*fft(x),10)==round(x%*%t(E),10)
```

Now I should be able to recover `x` using

```
 Re(colSums(c(x%*%t(E))*E))
```

but this gives

[1] -0.50219235  0.11697127  0.88678481 -0.07891709  0.13153117

while `x` is equal to

[1] -0.50219235  0.13153117 -0.07891709  0.88678481  0.11697127

So I recover `x` but the order of the entries is changed. The first entry is still the first entry but other entries are mixed. Could anyone explain why this happens or what I am doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The first number is always the same, the remaining numbers are always in reverse order, for any size `n`. So if you do the operation twice you get the original order. The matrix `E` is symmetrical so it is not necessary to transpose it. I cannot see anything wrong in what you are doing and I am not sure of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The DFT matrix is not orthogonal, therefore the transpose of the matrix is not equal to the inverse. As such you are not undoing the operation by multiplying by the transpose of the matrix.

Since the matrix is symmetrical and the transpose is identical, then what you have done is multiplied the vector by the matrix squared. The square of this matrix does happen to be orthogonal, and as such acts as a coordinate translation (i.e order of entries is changed).

```
round( Re( E %*% E ), 10)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    1    0    0    0    0
## [2,]    0    0    0    0    1
## [3,]    0    0    0    1    0
## [4,]    0    0    1    0    0
## [5,]    0    1    0    0    0
```

This matrix is symmetric and orthogonal, and as such is equal to its own transpose and its inverse.

Your code and set up is correct; and for a bit of confirmation that this is the case you can use the built in fast-Fourier transform function `fft`

```
Re(fft(fft(1:10)))/10
##  [1]  1 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2
```

When used twice on a set of numbers it also alters the order in the same manner.